# No se puede crear una carpeta ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

mi dilema es que cuando trato de crear una carpeta en el sistema, no lo hace y me muestra un error.

> No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso
>   'C:\Users\Administracion\Desktop\WebApplication1\FileBrowserVentas\Vouchers\46318100\aaa.png'.
>   Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web
>   actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información
>   acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: No se
>   puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso
>   'C:\Users\Administracion\Desktop\WebApplication1\FileBrowserVentas\Vouchers\46318100\aaa.png'.

Mi código es el siguiente:

.ASPX

```
    <table class="kt-datatable__table" style="display: block;width: 600px;border: 2px solid;">
        <tbody class="kt-datatable__body ps ps--active-y">
            <th class="kt-datatable__row">
                <div class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                    Subir Vouchers de Pago / Separaciones
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </th>
            <tr data-row="0" class="kt-datatable__row" style="left: 0px;">
                <td data-field="ShipName" data-autohide-disabled="false" class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                    <span>                        
                        <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                            Busqueda de Cliente
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td data-field="ShipName" data-autohide-disabled="false" class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                    <span>                        
                        <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ClienteBusqueda" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DNICreate" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td data-field="ShipName" data-autohide-disabled="false" class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                    <span>                        
                        <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                            <asp:Button ID="BusquedaCliente" runat="server" Text="Buscar Cliente" OnClick="BusquedaCliente_Click"/>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-row="0" class="kt-datatable__row" style="left: 0px;">
                <td data-field="ShipName" data-autohide-disabled="false" class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                    <span>                        
                        <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                            <asp:FileUpload  runat="server" ID="fuSample" />
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-row="0" class="kt-datatable__row" style="left: 0px;">
                <td data-field="ShipName" data-autohide-disabled="false" class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                    <span>                        
                        <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                            <asp:Button  runat="server" Enabled="false" ID="btnUpload" Text="Subir documentos" class="btn btn-info" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-row="0" class="kt-datatable__row" style="left: 0px;">
                <td data-field="ShipName" data-autohide-disabled="false" class="kt-datatable__cell alineacion-centro">
                    <span>                        
                        <div class="kt-user-card-v2">
                            <div id="alertasubida" class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <div class="alert-text"><asp:Label runat="server" class="" ID="lblMessage" Text=""></asp:Label></div>
                </div>

                        </div>
                    </span>
                </td>
                </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Files is folder Name
    string Paxh = @"/FileBrowserVentas/Vouchers/" + DNICreate.Text + "";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Paxh))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Paxh);
    }
    fuSample.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Paxh) + "//" + fuSample.FileName);
    lblMessage.Text = "Se subió correctamente al servidor.";
    alertasubida.Visible = true;
}
```

El problema se origina aqui:

> string Paxh = @"/FileBrowserVentas/Vouchers/" + DNICreate.Text + "";

Cual podria ser la solución ?

Gracias de antemano !

Comment: Parece que c# no puede encontrar aaa.png o una de las carpetas en la ruta. Ha verificado que existen?

Comment: Sí, la idea es que se cree la carpeta si no existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A los que tengan el mismo error, mi solucion fue añadir un using:

```
Using System.IO;
```

A su vez, añadir el codigo "ServerMapPath" dentro "Directory"

```
        string Paxh = "/FileBrowserVentas/Vouchers/" + DNICreate.Text;
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(Paxh)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(Paxh));
        }
        fuSample.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Paxh) + "//" + fuSample.FileName);
        lblMessage.Text = "Se subió correctamente al servidor.";
        alertasubida.Visible = true;
```

Con eso, se crea la carpeta con el nombre del TextBox, en este caso "DNICreate" y se añaden los archivos al Uploader.

Answer (score 1):

Repetir código no es una buena práctica, prueba de esta manera:

```
    string Paxh = Server.MapPath("/FileBrowserVentas/Vouchers/" + DNICreate.Text);
    if (!Directory.Exists(Paxh))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Paxh);
    }
    fuSample.SaveAs(Paxh + "//" + fuSample.FileName);
    lblMessage.Text = "Se subió correctamente al servidor.";
    alertasubida.Visible = true;
```